# Shortest superstring for words of size 2

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an alphabet of size 5 and a set of words of size 2. I want to find the shortest superstring of the set. I know i can find an approximation with the greedy algorithm, but is there an algorithm that can find an exact solution ? I feel like this could be possible given all the constraints on the problem but i couldn't figure out anything (even with an alphabet of size 3).

Comment: can you please tell us what is the definition of : **the shortest superstring of the set**, thanks. is it the [Shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem)  ?

Comment: It's the string that contains every word of the set. So "ABC" is the shortest superstring of {"AB", "BC"} (see for exemple here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-superstring-problem/). I guess it is also named "shortest common supersequence problem", but i've mostly seen it named "shortest superstring problem" in the litterature.

Comment: The chapter on Shortest superstring from researchgate can help you : 
 [chapter link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286139780_The_Shortest_Superstring_Problem)

Comment: With an alphabet of size 3 and words of size 2, there are only 9 possible words. If the set of words contains duplicates, the duplicates can be removed. So the size of the set of words must be <= 9. You could try every possible order, since worst case there are only 362880 possible orders.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**: The Shortest Superstring Problem (SSP) is NP-hard problem for strings of length n ≥ 3 . And for n <= 2, there is linear time and space algorithm.

**Detail:**

Frome the abstract of chapter ([Shortest Superstring Problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286139780_The_Shortest_Superstring_Problem)) on researchgate:
The **Shortest Superstring Problem (SSP)** is a combinatorial optimization
problem.  **The SSP is an [NP-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)**, and therefore great effort to develop ***exact algorithms for it has not been made***.  On the other hand, several approximation and heuristic algorithms have been implemented indicating the strong effectiveness of the greedy strategies to this problem.

you can also refer to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem)

Now, if you want to apply the SSP only on **very small alphabet** and **very small set** where the strings also are of **very small size**, you can go with very naive solution of combining all the possibilities.

**Edit 1:** While chatting with a friend of mine about this problem, I discovered that ***there is a linear solution to the special case of strings of size 2***.

In the paper [**On finding minimal length superstrings**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000080900045) (1980), the authors prove that the Shortest Superstring Problem (SSP) is NP-hard problem for strings of length n ≥ 3 . And they prove that for n <= 2, there is linear time and space algorithm to this specific case.

***COROLLARY 2.1. There is a linear time and space algorithm to find a minimal length superstring for a set of strings of length less than or equal to 2.***

The algorithm (use a directed graph) and the proof is given at the pages 54 and 55.

**Edit 2:** a simple algorithm steps and example for strings of length 2 in polynomial time, from the paper
[Approximating Shortest Superstring Problem Using de Bruijn Graphs](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Ebenkoczi/files/papers/ssp-Bruijn.pdf)

Algorithm steps:

- 1. we first construct the de Bruijn graph of the given set of 2-strings,
- 2. then for each weakly connected component we add edges between imbalanced vertices (i.e., vertices
     with non-zero difference of in-degree and out-degree) so that the resulting component contains an Eulerian path.
- 3. Finally, we add edges between components so that the graph contains an Eulerian path.

Example: let the list {KL, DB, DE, CK, BD, DA}, find the SSP in polynomial time.

[image]

- Fig (a) de Bruijn graph of a set of strings **{KL, DB, DE, CK, BD, DA}**.
- Fig (b) After adding an edge ED each weakly connected component contains an Eulerian path.
- Fig (c) The string **DBDEDACKL** spelled by a path going through all the edges is a shortest superstring.